# Simple CoreNLP : ClassNotFoundException

Tags: java, exception, servlets, stanford-nlp, libraries

My simple coreNLP code is working with main method as shown in code below.

```
    package com.books.servlet;

import edu.stanford.nlp.simple.Document;
import edu.stanford.nlp.simple.Sentence;

public class SimpleCoreNLPDemo {
    public static void main(String[] args) { 

        // Create a document. No computation is done yet.
        Document doc = new Document("add your text here! It can contain multiple sentences.");

        for (Sentence sent : doc.sentences()) {  

            // Will iterate over two sentences
            // We're only asking for words -- no need to load any models yet

            System.out.println("The second word of the sentence '" + sent + "' is " + sent.word(1));

            // When we ask for the lemma, it will load and run the part of speech tagger

            System.out.println("The third lemma of the sentence '" + sent + "' is " + sent.lemma(2));

            // When we ask for the parse, it will load and run the parser
            System.out.println("The parse of the sentence '" + sent + "' is " + sent.parse());

        }
    }
}
```

Then I used this code in my web application as below. when I execute the code. I get Below error and exception

My web app code

```
public void me(){

    Document doc = new Document("add your text here! It can contain multiple sentences.");

    for (Sentence sent : doc.sentences()) {  

        // Will iterate over two sentences
        // We're only asking for words -- no need to load any models yet

        System.out.println("The second word of the sentence '" + sent + "' is " + sent.word(1));

        // When we ask for the lemma, it will load and run the part of speech tagger
        System.out.println("The third lemma of the sentence '" + sent + "' is " + sent.lemma(2));

        // When we ask for the parse, it will load and run the parser
        System.out.println("The parse of the sentence '" + sent + "' is " + sent.parse());

} }
```

[image: Error]

[image]

> I have downloaded all the jar files and added to the build path. it is
>   working fine with main method

Answer (score 0):

I just resolved the problem.

I copied all my Stanford simple NLP jar file to the directory

> /WEB-INF/lib

and now my code is working fine. Below is my simple method and its output for your information.

```
public String s = "I like java and python";

public static Set<String> nounPhrases = new HashSet<>();

public void me() {

    Document doc = new Document(" " + s);
    for (Sentence sent : doc.sentences()) {

        System.out.println("The parse of the sentence '" + sent + "' is " + sent.parse());

                }
}
```

output

```
The parse of the sentence 'I like java and python' is (ROOT (S (NP (PRP I)) (VP (VBP like) (NP (NN java) (CC and) (NN python)))))
```